# Media Container is empty after the upload of an image in hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am uploading an image in online product catalog version. And when I check in the `Hybris Management Console` the `media container` is empty.
This is happening with the new products and not the old ones. Can you help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways to achieve this. 
On a running system you can use the HMC to upload an image to a Media. It ***should work*** out-of-the-box (that is, unless you changed sth on the constraints of your MedialModel in the typesystem). If it doesn't, we would need a stacktrace/errormessage, since this is not a usual behaviour.

The second way to do this is via Impex:

```
$resourceImport=jar:com.myextensionpackage.constants.MyExtensionConstants&/import
INSERT_UPDATE Media;code[unique=true];catalogVersion(catalog(id),version);@media[translator=de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.media.MediaDataTranslator];;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;testdata-media-1;<ignore>;$resourceImport/myImage.PNG;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Now you can put that image underneath

`$YOUREXTENSIONPATH/resources/import/myImage.png`

Hopefully that'll help.

Answer (score 0):

First You need to create a new media Using *HMC>MultiMedia>Media*. Then upload image, give it an identifier. **Now important step is to Sync this Media**. The option is right above where you created Media.
After that go to the *HMC>product* and add this product media to that product. There are other options though. If you want to add galleryImages in product, you can't add single media in it. Hence you need to create the mediaContainer and add all media to it. And then add this mediaContainer to the galleryImages in product tab.